How to measure light intensity in a room?
Does anyone know how I would go about measuring the light intensity in a room? I'm not interested in knowing the lux reading, I would like to measure the $W/m^2$ due to thermal radiation in my surroundings.
I have seen that some solar panel installers use 'Solar Irradiance Meters' but I'm not sure if these would work for measurement indoors in a lab/office.
The reason I want to know the light intensity is because I have a metal vacuum can with an optical window, and I wish to calculate how much of a heat load is entering throught the window due to surrounding EM radiation. If I know the light intensity of the surroundings, I can calculate how many watts heat load is entering the can.

The RP Photonics Buyer's Guide is a place to start looking. Detectors and Measurements

Thanks for your suggestion, I will investigate on there.
